# Can VSO Application Insights be used from a console application?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-application-insights

All the information that I can find on Application Insights seems to be targeted at websites / windows store / phone apps. I would like to monitor an Azure webjob, with the first step being able to monitor a command line app. What do I need to do in order to make this work?

Comment: What exactly do you want to monitor? Are you aware that Console.WriteLine and Trace.TraceInformation will get logged if you setup application logging for your site?

Comment: When you say 'get logged' do you mean that these are logged to app insights?

Comment: I'm after a centralised place to monitor a collection of small web apps each with one or more webjobs. I don't want to have to look at each web app for this info, I need to see the full behaviour of the system to see how a change flows from one site to another. I'm using Serilog to log a bunch of useful information about the progress of each of the webjobs. App insight diagnostics seems like it's the right fit for this, perhaps it's unsuitable?

Comment: Try the following: enable application diagnostics to table storage in all web apps using the same table name (and Azure storage account), all these web apps/WebJobs should write their log to System.Diagnostics.Trace, to view the logs go to one of your sites and install the Azure Website Log Browser site extension, use these instructions: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/06/azure-website-logging/ and you'll get a nice view of all your logs in the same table

Comment: Cheers Amit. That sounds like it will do what I need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To use Application Insights in a Console application,

- Create a new Application Insights resource as described [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-start-monitoring-app-health-usage/).
- Use the NuGet package manager reference the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` package in your console application.
- In the beginning of `Program.Main`, configure Application Insights to use the instrumentation key of your resource.

`TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = "your key";`

- Create instance of `TelemetryClient` in the application code and call relevant `Track` methods as described [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-web-track-usage).

Comment: I have the same problem and can't figure out why this is not working, tried Oleg's solution but no cigar. For some reason the code does not log anything, event or exception, it doesn't blow up either. 

I also tried passing the telemetryConfiguration object to the TelemetryClient but that is not working.

I have tried using the ApplicationInsights.config to store the key and that seems to still fill the key but I'm not logging anything still. I'm running version 1.1.0.1899 of Application Insights. Has anyone tried this solution successfully?

Comment: One common reason why nothing seems to get logged from console application is that it terminates before data is sent. Please use Flush method and ensure there's some delay and Flush is async. See more details here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30928231/788382

Answer (score -1):

Yes.You could be used Application Insights from a console application.

Technically there is no problem. But after setting everything up you find that no or partial data goes to Application Insights, not the entire data.

For this situation, you need to add thread.sleep at the end of the code.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        //do your stuff
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(70000);
   }
```