# TelemetryClient does not send any data unless Flush is called

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I'm using TelemetryClient (v0.17.0.576) directly in my code and it looks like I can push data to Azure only when I manually call Flush at the end which feels wrong. Am I missing something here ?

```
var configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
configuration.InstrumentationKey = "KEY";
var client = new TelemetryClient(configuration);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   log.Information("Loop: {0} {1}", i, value);

   client.Track(new TraceTelemetry(value));
}
client.Flush();
```

Comment: Is this C# or Java? The TelemetryClient listed on the Microsoft documentation site doesn't include a Flush method, so are you using the most recent release? Doe the Client support IDisposable (and if so does it Flush when Disposed?)

Comment: C#, the docs seems not be up to date.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For performance reasons, the Application Insights SDK batches telemetry and sends it up in chunks. To see this in action you can replace your Flush call with a call to Thread.Sleep (70000) and you will see the instrumentation uploaded to AI once the app terminates.

Comment: Added previously I would wait at a breakpoint of data to arrive. When I changed it to Console.ReadLine() everything started working.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Adding a breakpoint in the application will pause the entire application (until resumed) and as such the telemetry upload is also paused.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mario Hewardt's answer. If you use the [persistence channel](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-desktop/#persistence-channel):

```
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryChannel = new PersistenceChannel();
```

`Flush()` is synchronous (so you don't need sleep the thread for an abitrary length of time).  It also has the benefit of saving the telemetry data to a local file if Application Insights cannot be contacted, which will then be sent next time `Flush()` is called with a good connection.

Comment: A comment at the bottom of the linked article from a Microsoft resource claims that 'PersistenceChannel was part of Devices SDK that is in a maintenance mode'. Her suggested approach is to switch to HockeyApp or to try Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel from nuget

Comment: Unfortunately, Flush() does not block:
 https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/407

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep(30000) is working for me, but flush is not working in application. I would like to use Flush() method as i can't sleep my application for 30 seconds. Is Flush() method is related to version Specific or i am missing something else?

I have Console application which call another Console Library, which will further call another console library which have telemetry class (ie Console Application --> DLL --> DLL (having telemetry implementation)).

Answer (score 0):

The data does not need to be flushed - except when the application ends directly after sending the last trace. Unfortunately, Flush is not enough though, it doesn't block(*). So the recommendation is to do both flushing and five seconds of waiting.

(*)  https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/407